# Buttons Running Code Once

Tags: java, performance, button

I'm writing a program that uses a controller with many buttons to perform certain tasks. Basically, when a button is pressed, I want specific code to run, and only once. This is why I have `buttonWasPressed` to ensure the code is only run once when the buttons are pressed, and not every loop cycle.

```
while(active)
{
    if(button1)
        if(!buttonWasPressed)
        {
            code1();
            buttonWasPressed = true;
        }
    else if(button2)
        if(!buttonWasPressed)
        {
            code2();
            buttonWasPressed = true;
        }
    else if(button3)
        if(!buttonWasPressed)
        {
            code3();
            buttonWasPressed = true;
        }
    .
    .
    .
    else
        buttonWasPressed = false;
}
```

I'm mainly just wondering if there's a better way to write this, because there's a lot of unnecessary repetition with checking and setting `buttonWasPressed`. I thought about using a switch statement, but those need to have constants for the cases, which this code doesn't have. I also can't use arrays for the buttons, so a for loop probably wouldn't work. Ideally, I'd like the code to look something like this:

```
while(active)
{
    if(button1)
        code1()
    else if(button2)
        code2();
    else if(button3)
        code3();
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Except where the code is only run once per button press. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What do button1, button2.. signify? Do they tell which button is pressed? If so, then why do you need another variable buttonWasPressed to indicate if the button is pressed

Comment: button1, 2, etc. are booleans that represent whether or not that specific button is pressed at any given moment. buttonWasPressed is used to make it so the code only runs once when the button is pressed. If that variable wasn't there, the code would get run once per loop, which I don't want.

Comment: Then what does active do? your while loop will execute irrespective of which button is clicked if active is true. So, in order to run loop only once you will have to set active=false inside each of the if

Comment: For the sake of this code, you can treat active as always true. It can't be turned to false, because other code is also being run in the loop (not shown here, because it's irrelevant). And setting active to false would mean that only one button could ever be pressed, then the loop would exit. I need to be able to press the buttons more than once when the program is running.

Comment: It is still little unclear. Suppose if button1 is pressed then button1 is true and button2, button3 ..will be false. The code under if for button1 will only be executed, code for button2, button3 .. will not run.So, If you set button1=false inside the if then the code for button1 will only get executed next time and only once when button1 is pressed i.e when button1 is true.

Comment: The values of the buttons shouldn't be manually changed. They get assigned to the current states of the physical buttons I'm using every loop cycle. They're basically getter methods, but just haven't been written that way. Even if I did manually change them, the values would automatically get reassigned in the next loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work by just waiting for all of the buttons to be released before going to the next cycle. The code looks like this now:

```
while(active)
{
    if(button1)
        code1()
    else if(button2)
        code2();
    else if(button3)
        code3();
    .
    .
    .

    while(!buttonsAreReleased());
}
```

This may not work in other applications because of the empty while loop holding things up, but it worked for me. I had to make the method that checks to see if the buttons are released:

```
boolean buttonsAreReleased()
{
    return !(button1 || button2 || ...);
}
```